# Action receive my object but all properties are null

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, post, null

I'm trying to send a object by jquery post, to an action in asp.net MVC 4
but every time i send it, in the action i receive only the object but all properties are null.

Note that if i send 2 itens in the child array, in the server the object have the 2 objects in the array, but again, all the properties are null.

My javascript:

```
    var pacote = {
        contato: obj,
        listaTelefones: telefones,
        listaEmails: emails
    };

    console.log(JSON.stringify(pacote));

    $.post(form.attr("action"), pacote, function (data) {
    });

THE CONSOLE.LOG RESULT:

{ 
            "contato" : { 
                "DataNascimento" : "11/04/1993",
                "Departamento" : "desenv",
                "IdCliente" : "2",
                "IdContato" : "",
                "Nome" : "jean",
                "Observacoes" : "testando",
                "Sobrenome" : "alves"
            },
            "listaEmails" : [ { 
                "Endereco" : "myemail@gmail.com",
                "Tipo" : "Tipo 2"
            } ],
            "listaTelefones" : [ { 
                "Numero" : "5185927878",
                "Tipo" : "Tipo 1"
            } ]
        }


MY ACTION:

        public ActionResult GravarContato(DTOContrato dtoContrato)
        {
        }
```

THE DTOContrato class:

```
public class DTOContrato
{
    public Contato contato { get; set; }
    public List<Telefone> listaTelefones { get; set; }
    public List<Email> listaEmails { get; set; }

    public class Contato
    {
        public int IdContato { get; set; }
        public int IdCliente { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Sobrenome { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DataNascimento { get; set; }
        public string Departamento { get; set; }
        public string Observacoes { get; set; }
    }

    public class Telefone
    {
        public string Tipo;
        public string Numero;
    }

    public class Email
    {
        public string Tipo;
        public string Endereco;
    }
}
```

thanks everyone

Comment: Can you post the controller code?

Comment: Hard to tell with out seeing the controller method, but it probably needs to be `$.post(form.attr("action"), { pacote: pacote }, function (data) {..` if `pacote` if the name of the method parameter

Comment: I've changed the $.post for $.ajax, put contenttype and datatype to json and now it working. 
Anyway, thanks for helping!!